# A relation on the set of real numbers which is only reflexive.

Tags: relations

Can we construct a relation R on the set of real numbers such that it is only reflexive & neither symmetric nor transitive?

Comment: I'd try something like $a\sim b$ iff $0≤a-b≤1$.

Comment: I’d just start with the relation of equality and add two ordered pairs chosen to create a violation of transitivity.

Answer (score 2):

I claim that almost any attempt to build such a relation will succeed. Take any reflexive relation, select two distinct elements and use them to break symmetry, and select three other distinct elements and use them to break transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

A binary relation on the real numbers is any subset of ${\Bbb R}{\times}{\Bbb R}$.

Let $R$ be any reflexive, symmetric, and transitive relation on ${\Bbb R}$. Select two arbitrary but distinct elements $a$ and $b$ from ${\Bbb R}$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ and construct a new relation $R_1$ as follows:

$$ R_1 = R \setminus\{(a,b)\}$$

Now $R_1$ is reflexive because $R$ is.

$R_1$ is not symmetric since $(b,a)\in R_1$ (because $(b,a)\in R$ being symmetric) but $(a,b) \notin R_1$.

To show that $R_1$ is not transitive, take any element $c\neq a,b\in {\Bbb R}$ such that $(a,c)\in R$ and $(c,b)\in R$.

From this construction, we see that it's necessary to require that the domain of $R$ has at least cardinality three otherwise we wouldn't be able to pick the $a, b, c$ needed for the non-symmetry and non-transitivity of $R_1$.